Base and dimension of the vector space of a matrix.
Find a basis and the dimension of the vector space of polynomials in the matrix $A,$ over $\mathbb{R}$, where $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \omega & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \omega^{2} \end{bmatrix},\quad\omega=\frac{\sqrt{3}i-1}{2}.$$
For example, $A^3 − A^2 + 5A + I_3$ is one such polynomial.
My attempt: Let's look at the following

$\omega^3=1.$
$\omega^2+\omega+1=0.$
$A^3=I_3.$
The characteristic polynomial $$\chi_A(\lambda)=det(A-\lambda I_3)=1-\lambda^3.$$
The minimal polynomial $$\mu_A=\chi_A.$$

My intuition tells me that a basis for the vector space of polynomials in the matrix $A$ is $$\{1,X,X^2,X^3\},$$ because any $P$ polynomial in the matrix $A$ such that $P(A)=0$ is a multiple of $\mu_A.$ Although I don't know what happens with polynomials similar to the example they provide in the exercise.
Any suggestions?

See that $X^3=I_3.$ So, you need to remove $X^3$ from your basis set.

You have $A^3=I $, so any polynomial in $A$ can be written as an expression of at most degree $2$. That is, $\{I,A,A^2\}$ span the space of polynomials in $A$. It remains to show that they are linearly independent. For this you can notice that if $I,A,A^2$ are linearly dependent, you will have a polynomial of degree less than three that annihilates $A$, contradicting that the minimal polynomial of $A$ has degree three.
For another way to see the linear independence, you have
$$
A^2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &-1- \omega & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \omega \end{bmatrix}
$$
So suppose that
$$
\alpha I+\beta A+\gamma A^2=0.
$$
This looks like
\begin{align}
0&=\begin{bmatrix} \alpha+\beta+\gamma & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \alpha+\beta\omega+\gamma(-1-\omega) & 0 \\
0 & 0 &\alpha+\beta\omega^2+\gamma \omega \end{bmatrix}.\\[0.2cm]
\end{align}
This gives us a homogenous linear system on $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ with matrix
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\1&\omega&-1-\omega\\1&-1-\omega&\omega
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Via row reduction
$$
\det M=\det\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\0&\omega-1&-2-\omega\\0&-2-\omega&\omega-1
\end{bmatrix}=(\omega-1)^2(\omega+2)^2\ne0,
$$
since $\omega $ is not real, so $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$.
